# Rewriting all java.time uses to ThreeTen-Backport

Tags: java, java-time, threetenbp

[Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) allows conversion of Java 8 class files to Java 7 format (and before). It explicitly doesn't backport Java 8 APIs. If I want to also replace all references to `java.time.*` with corresponding `org.threeten.bp.*` API, is there a way to do so? The idea is to produce separate JARs for Java 8 (using `java.time`) and for Java 7.

Comment: I would create a build of threetenbp which uses the `java.time` package.  This way you don't need to change your code to migrate to Java 8.

Comment: This is a good idea, but a bytecode-rewriting solution could also handle methods like `Date.toInstant` (or be extended to do so). Still, it gets most of the way there, thanks!

Comment: defining classes in java.* outside of the JVM installation is a no-no